# How to destroy current screen completely while navigating to previous screen on back press in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, navigation, state, state-management

I am listening to a stream and calling setState on the completion of stream in a screen.

When i press back the screen disappears but the in the background it keeps working and eventually call set state and gives me the following error :

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _HotelPriceScreenState#4ec39(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
E/flutter ( 2203): This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.

E/flutter ( 2203): The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
E/flutter ( 2203): This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().

How to tackle that situation and completely stop the current screen so that it stop listening to the stream and won't call setState().

Comment: I assume you @override dispose() and cleaned everything up?

Comment: @JonnH i call channel.sink.close() on dispose() which should close the stream.

Comment: Then check mounted() before calling setState()

Comment: how to call that ? i'm listening to a stream using through a web socket channel.
StreamBuilder(
      stream: widget.channel.stream,
)
and closing it in the dispose method 
channel.sink.close() - like this.

i've put the logs. dispose is called first and after done is called.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure that I understand your problem, but as far as I can see flutter gave you there a useful error message.

Like it says in the error text, you could either stop listening to the stream in `dispose()` (or pause it or close it or something else) or you could check the `.mounted` value before calling `setState()` (this would be the best solution in my opinion). So instead of calling `setState()` immediately, just wrap `setState()` inside another function and return if the Widget is mounted before calling `setState()`.

I really hope I could help and please don't be too harsh, this is my first post.

Comment: I did get the error message and also did use the mounted. It kinda worked for me but i wanted to know the reason why it's happening.

Comment: dispose doesn't work on navigating away.